# image is not being displayed in UIImageView when it's set even though it's being called on the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UICollectionView with a UIImageView as the header (named `AddPhotoHeader`). The background is set to grey, but once the image is selected in the next controller (named `PhotoSelectorController`) it's supposed to return to the original UICollectionView with the image in the UIImageView.

This is in the `AddPhotoHeader`:

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView.image = (self.selectedImage)!
            print("This is the selectedImage:", (self.selectedImage)!)
        }
        imageView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}


let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 234, green: 246, blue: 246)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()
```

In the `PhotoSelectorController`, this is where the photos are fetched:

```
fileprivate func fetchPhotos() {
    let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: assetsFetchOptions())

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        allPhotos.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in
            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isSynchronous = true
            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                if let image = image {
                    self.images.append(image)
                    self.assets.append(asset)

                    if self.selectedImage == nil {
                        self.selectedImage = image
                    }
                }

                if count == allPhotos.count - 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            })

        })
    }
}
```

After the user chooses the photo and clicks "Next", this function is called to put the image in the UIImageView of the `AddPhotoHeader`

```
@objc func handleNext() {
    let addPhotoHeader = AddPhotoHeader()
    addPhotoHeader.selectedImage = header?.photoImageView.image
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

And the print statement in the `selectedImage` prints out:

```
This is the selectedImage: <UIImage: 0x6000028510a0>, {485, 482}
```

But it just stays as a grey rectangle, no image is showing up in the UIImageView of the `AddPhotoHeader`

I feel like I'm missing an obvious step here but I just haven't been able to figure it out. Hopefully you can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: The “Debug View Hierarchy” button can be useful in diagnosing problems like this, to figure out whether the problem is that the image view hasn’t been added to the view hierarchy (which seems like a likely culprit to me as I don’t see you doing `addSubview` of `AddPhotoHeader`’s `imageView` anywhere); or that it is added and that its frame makes it non-visible (either a `frame.size` of `.zero` or `.origin` that places it outside of the visible rect); or that the image view’s `image` hasn’t been changed like you thought it should have been. “Debug View Hierarchy” should help you diagnose this.

Comment: I assume `handleNext()` is in `PhotoSelectorController`? You're creating a _new_ `AddPhotoHeader`, setting the `selectedImage` on it and then dismissing. This is _not_ your original `AddPhotoHeader`. So the `print` gets executed and _poof_ it's gone.

Comment: @Rob I'm currently doing that to see if i can diagnose the problem, ill let ya know if I figure it out that way!

Comment: @Don You're correct, `handleNext()` is in `PhotoSelectorController`. What you're saying makes sense. Can you think of a solution on how to replace the original `AddPhotoHeader` rather than creating a new one?

Comment: You can use delegation or a callback closure. If you do a quick search on this site of how to send data back to previous view controller, you'll find plenty of great answers and you can choose the one that suits your style best.